# Oracle APEX Unable to create work space

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I just installed the oracle apex in my local machine. But when I tried to create a new work space, it shows below error and doesn't allow me to create the work space.

```
Error provisioning test.
ORA-20001: Request 2601726233960171 could not be processed. -20987 ORA-20987: APEX - Unable to
create user. ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name - ORA-65096: 
common user or role name
```

Thank you!

Comment: What username did you use when selecting associated schema?

Comment: I used ADMIN. But I tried with different user names and I got the same result.

Comment: highly unlikely ADMIN exists as a schema in the database, well, one that you'd be associating your application with. It may validate against it, causing your error. You need to select a valid database schema for "schema name", or re-use an existing one.

Comment: Maybe it's a 12c issue http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60806/oracle-12c-create-user

Comment: It can be created using an existing schema. But I can not create with a new schema.

Comment: so is it on 12c? does the new schema comply with the suggestions in the link?